# How can I add a relative path to submit an HTML form?

Tags: html, forms, path, relative-path

I want to use a relative path for form submitting an HTML form. I have tried `./submit` but it does not work.

CodeIgniter + Generated code:

```
echo form_open('./submit');
// <form action="http://example.com/./submit" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

This is what I want:

```
http://example.com/seekerpanel/changepassword/submit
```

And this is what I get:

```
http://example.com/submit
```

How can I address this path as relative to `changepassword` page?

Comment: Is the actual URL of the page the form is on `http://domain.com/seekerpanel/changepassword/` ?

Comment: Yes. and I'm using Code Igniter

Comment: Any chance you could post the code for the actual form? The whole form tag would be nice to see. Also, are you using a `<base>` tag in your header? And finally, check the form with your browser's inspector, make sure the URL isn't being changed when the page is being loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could do this using current_url function in url helper.

This generates the required output:

```php
echo form_open(current_url().'/submit');
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I don't think Anyone will come to this question because the issue of relative path was raised and resolved in 2015, But if anyone is getting error do check other parameter such as "method" and see to it that you have entered the correct value.

Answer (score -3):

Would you not just add the relative path  `http://example.com/seekerpanel/changepassword/submit` into the action form attribute?

```
<form action="http://example.com/seekerpanel/changepassword/submit" method="get">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: because it's neither relative nor a path nor anything remotely resembling a good practice.